# Next.js: useMemo and useState synchronization problem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hooks, react-i18next

```
const initialProjectsWL: ProjectWL[] = useMemo(() => {

        const arr: ProjectWLDraft[] = t('whiteLabel.projects', {returnObjects: true})

        const newArr: ProjectWL[] = arr.map((el, idx) => {
            return {
                ...el,
                isActive: false,
                className: `project-${idx}`
            }
        })

        return newArr;
    }, [t])

const [projectsWL, setProjectsWl] = useState(initialProjectsWL);
```

I'm still new to next.js and react.js . There is an i18next in my react component. As you can see in the useMemo hook there is a callback that returns an array of objects depending on t. And this array goes to the useState hook as the initial value. The problem is that when I change the locale in i18next, my initialProjectsWL changes, but the projectsWL does not change.

Comment: State won't update like that (`useState` doesn't track the initial value, and `useMemo` changes won't retrigger `useState` calls). You probably don't need `useMemo` here. `useState` + `useEffect` should work.

Answer (score 1):

The [`useState` initial state](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#parameters) is only used once for the state:

> **The value you want the state to be initially**. It can be a value of any
> type, but there is a special behavior for functions. **This argument is
> ignored after the initial render.**

However, you don't need the state at all. When the `i18next` changes (`t`), the component re-renders, and since `t` have changed, the `useMemo` computes new value synchronously, and it can be used directly in the component, without setting it to a state.

So the solution is simple, remove the state, and rename `initialProjectsWL` to `projectsWL`:

```
const projectsWL: ProjectWL[] = useMemo(() => {
```